# Do the skipped manga chapters involve any romantic developments?

Tags: dagashi-kashi

I was reading about *Dagashi Kashi* and saw that around 30 chapters had been skipped in the anime adaptation of the show. I've heard that the skipped chapters focused much more on Hotaru-san than the anime does. Personally, I'd like to read through those chapters if theres some romance introduced between the characters.

While the anime consists mostly of gags involving dagashi, there are some moments where we get to learn about Saya's feelings, like in the flashback of them playing doctor. However, it seems to be pretty one-sided, with Kokonotsu being completely oblivious. What kind of romantic developments or situations can I expect if I read through the manga?